# How to use left and right mouse buttons to navigate back and forward in Firefox

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, browser, mouse

In Chrome and some other browsers you can use the 3rd and 4th mouse buttons to navigate forward and back in the browser history. In Firefox this brings up a scroll wheel. Is there a way to change Firefox to go back and forth in the browser history?

[image]

Comment: What model mouse are you using, and did you do anything unusual to map the buttons?

Comment: I haven't changed anything. Back and forward work in Chrome and other programs. But in Firefox it shows the icon shown.

Comment: What kind of mouse, though? Does it have a middle button and a scroll wheel, plus the left and right buttons?

Comment: Yes. It has left and right plus middle click plus two on the side. No mouse software but OSX. No mapping.

Comment: Also having this issue, it's a bit frustrating.